# Passing URL parameters to Iframe on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, iframe

I'm trying to pass some parameters to an Iframe and it works fine in all browsers, except IE.

I couldn't find any other solution for what I'm trying to do, but maybe IE doesn't accept parameters to be sent to an iframe?

This is what I have:

```
 <iframe src="https://portal.maxistore.com.br/dologin.php?
 email=<?php echo urlencode($user_info->user_login) ?>&timestamp=<?php echo urlencode($timestamp) ?>&hash=<?php echo $hash ?>&goto=<?php echo urlencode($goto_invoices) ?>" name="iframeTarget" id="iframeTarget" width="100%" height="1200px"></iframe>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can u construct and `echo` entire iframe code in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

My answer has nothing to do with IE compatibility directly... I just wanted to point out a much more efficient way to build urls. Although, it may be beneficial to do it the proper way and eliminate the margin for error when building your urls.

With the use of [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) and [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/sprintf) you can build dynamic encoded urls with a single function versus all this interdom php code. Check it out:

**Example**

```
$Data = [
    'timestamp' => time(),
    'id' => 64,
    'email' => 'bobbyryan@aol.com',
];

$url = http_build_query($Data);

echo sprintf("http://www.example.com/?%s", $url);
```

**Results in the following URL**

```
http://www.example.com/?timestamp=1367951475&id=64&email=bobbyryan%40aol.com
```